# python: how to print separate lines from a list?

Tags: python, python-3.x, class, append

This is my code:

```
class Message:

    def __init__(self,sender,recipient):
        self.sender = sender
        self.recipient = recipient
        self.wishList = []

    def append(self,line):
        self.wishList.append(str(line))
        for i in line:
            return i

    def toString(self):
        return 'From:{}\nTo:{}\n{}'.format(self.sender,self.recipient,
                                           self.wishList)
```

and the output is:

```
From:Aria

To:Santa

['For Christmas, I would like:', 'Video games', 'World peace']
```

How can I separate the lines and make the output as following?

```
From:Aria

To:Santa

For Christmas, I would like:

Video games

World peace
```

Comment: Look at `join` in the docs: `'\n'.join(lst)` will give you a string made up of all the strings in `lst` with newlines between them.

Comment: `'\n'.join(['For Christmas, I would like:', 'Video games', 'World peace'])` prints those wishes on three lines.

Answer (score 1):

You can convert list to string by `"joinerchar".join(list)`. In your code it will be like this.

```
return 'From:{}\nTo:{}\n{}'.format(self.sender,self.recipient,
                                       "\n".join(self.wishList))
```

Answer (score 1):

Imagine your array is `arr`

Then do `"\n".join(arr)` it basically takes the array and inserts a new line between each one.

With that example, you should be able to figure it out :) Comment if you need more help.

Answer (score 0):

First, some observations:

1. why are you returning the first character after adding an element to your wishList? (I consider it useless, so I have removed it from my answer)
2. I think you should add *For Christmas, I would like:* as part of your template to print.
3. using `str.join()` is probably the best alternative to concatenate the elements of the wishList.
4. Have you ever heard of [PEP-8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/?), basically it seems that you come from a language as Java or C# since you are using upperCamelCase, in Python `_` is preferred.
5. I don't think that converting line to `str` is relevant assuming you are going to enter a string, but let's leave it.

Assuming you are using Python 3.6+, you can use string interpolation:

```
class Message:
    def __init__(self, sender, recipient):
        self.sender = sender
        self.recipient = recipient
        self.wish_list = []

    def append(self, line):
        self.wish_list.append(str(line))

    def toString(self):
        nl = '\n'
        return f'From: {self.sender}{nl}To: {self.recipient}{nl}For Christmas, I would like:{nl}{nl.join(self.wish_list)}'
```

If you run the following code:

```
m = Message('Aria', 'Santa')
m.append('Video games')
m.append('World peace')
print(m.toString())
```

The output will be:

```
From: Aria
To: Santa
For Christmas, I would like:
Video games
World peace
```

Comment: @AriaBB, would you mind validating this answer if this worked?